# nullable property lost when updating model from database (EF6) in db first approach

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using **database first** approach, database which does not have any `foreign key` relationship (Association). I tried it in `edmx` file but foreign key scalar property must not `nullable`, which explicitly gets set false in `edmx`.

I want is : to make changes from database & use update model from database that scalar property must not get reset to **nullable none**.
How to maintain `nullable` property as it is, after updating model from database in `entity framework 6`?

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604004/how-to-preserve-non-nullable-setting-in-edmx-when-refreshing-model) with possible solution.  In EF4, manual changes would persist through a DB update.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first course should be to fix your database if the columns are never null then they shouldn't be nullable.  Then you could put the foreign keys in and have them created in the entity framework.

I came here with a problem that views have a nullable property of (none) even when they will always have a value so a simple example view

```
CREATE VIEW [CountItems]
AS
SELECT OrderItem.Sku, COUNT(*) as total FROM OrderItem
GROUP BY OrderItem.Sku
```

gives you

```
public partial class CountItems
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> total { get; set; }
}
```

despite the fact that the total could never be null.  The trick to get EF to know that it'll never be null is to use a pointless ISNULL

```
ALTER VIEW [CountItems]
AS
SELECT OrderItem.Sku, ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) as total FROM OrderItem
GROUP BY OrderItem.Sku
```

Then EF database first update model from database will get the hint and create it as not nullable

Hope that might help.

Comment: The question is actually the opposite, they want to keep the "Nullable" set to false but it gets reset to "None". This is a common scenario if you are using TPH and this is the recommended way to do from Microsoft.